Microphones don't work after 24.04 upgrade
My microphones don't work anymore after upgrading to 24.04 on a Lenovo Yoga 730-13IWL laptop.
I tried Ubuntu default kernel 6.8.0 and 6.9.1 from Ubuntu mainline kernel installer app.
On Fedora 40 it's all working well, so it should not be a hardware problem.
I tried integrated mic, cable headphones with mic, bluetooth headphones with mic (huawei freebuds 5i), but I had no luck.
I need guidance to dig into logs and pipewire configuration.
~$ inxi -A
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Cannon Point-LP High
    Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
  API: ALSA v: k6.9.1-060901-generic
    status: kernel-api
  Server-1: PipeWire v: 1.0.5 status: active

~$ LANG=C pactl list sources | grep Mute
    Mute: no
    Mute: no


Could you check if the mics are muted? LANG=C pactl list sources | grep Mute should do this for you.

@emk2203 added above. Strangely, pulseaudio-utils was not installed, or maybe got removed in the upgrade. pulseaudio package is also not present, thought it would cooperate with pipewire. alsa-base package is installed. Ubuntu first install is maybe 2017, from then on I've always upgraded

Try with a live flash media of ubuntu 24.04 and see if this works. You could copy the audio stuff from /etc to your distro if the mics work in the live media.
Personally, I would reinstall from scratch. Carrying 7 years of cruft often has these things as side effects.

@emk2203 i got news, if i create a new user then that user sees the mic and can use it normally. So the problem is limited to my user. Guess i have to erase any config file related to audio in my ~/home and hope the system recreates default config files for my user

Found it (somewhat)! i've just removed all the files from ~/.local/state/wireplumber , namely : default-nodes, default-profile , default-routes , policy-bluetooth, restore-stream. Don't exactly know why, but it worked!

For future reference, something got messed up in ~/.local/state/wireplumber so just remove the content there and let the system rebuild its files

This worked for me: Acer Nitro 5 - Ubuntu 24.04

It worked for me. My Jabra Evolve2 Buds has a very poor mic quality since I upgraded Ubuntu to 24.04. I fixed it by removing the directory and rebooting.

In case erasing /wireplumber folder content doesn't work, I had the same problem with my Blue Yeti not being detected as an input. What fixed it for me was installing pavucontrol, that way it was easier to view and modify the audio settings without digging in config files. There I could see the microphone being detected then edited Configuration->Profile as Digital Input.
I believe it's because some mics work both as input and output and sometimes only get detected as one of those.
